# Merging several convolutional layers into one

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

How can I compose several convolutional layers into one layer. I mean if there is no non-linear activations in between. How do I write a code for it in pytorch?

I want the code to account for different padding and strides. I thought about having a template image and run the conv layers on it to obtain one kernel, but can't really come up with a meaningful way to do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-the-pytorch-convolutions-work-or-how-to-collapse-two-convolutions-into-one-6dc810489d79) there are detailed instructions for collapsing 2 convolution layers into 1.
You can use the code to merge the first two and then to merge the outcome with the third.

Conceptually, you can vision the process in a simpler way by using the '[Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix)' represantaion of each convolution operation, then use matrix multiplication to multiply all three, and then return to one convolution operation (since it is more efficiently implemented, and the Toeplitz representation is very sparse).

> The convolution operation can be constructed as a matrix multiplication, where one of the inputs is converted into a Toeplitz matrix.

You can see an example of this approach [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix#Discrete_convolution).